# Docker JBoss SVN automation script? RPM v. YUM?

Tags: docker, svn, jboss, rpm, yum

As it stands, my Dockerfile works as written below, but currently I have to run the two commented lines in order to pull, compile, and deploy my application to the server. I tried creating a shell script to run those commands using ADD and ENTRYPOINT, but when I run (using the docker commands below) the shell script runs and then the container exits.

What/How do I modify (I'm assuming, the docker run command) to fix this?

Is there an easier way to import libraries than the multiple URLS for RPM? I tried using YUM, but I wasn't sure how to set up my repo for installing anything.

Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap71-openshift
USER root
RUN rpm -i [the URLS of the 40 libraries I need for SVN]
ADD subversion_installer_1.14.1.sh /home/svn_installer.sh
RUN yes | /home/svn_installer.sh 
USER jboss
ARG REPO_USER
ARG REPO_PW
ARG REPO_URL
ENV REPO_USER=$REPO_USER
ENV REPO_PW=$REPO_PW
ENV REPO_URL=$REPO_URL
#RUN svn export --username="$REPO_USER" --password="$REPO_PW" "$REPO_URL" /usr/svn/myapp
#RUN /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/bin/jar -cvf $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/myapp.war /usr/svn/myapp
```

Docker commands

```
docker build . -t myapp:latest
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 9990:9990 --env-file=svnvars.cfg myapp:latest
```

Comment: Adding a call to start the jboss server in the shell script keeps the container running. I can access localhost:8080/, but not localhost:8080/myapp, though I can see from the jboss log that that myapp.war is deployed.

Comment: So close I can taste it. Added ant to image and an ant build file to my code. Been reading and I now understand why the container exits, but not sure how to fix that. If I run the Dockerfile without the ENTRYPOINT, JBoss starts and runs, but I have to manually run the shell script. If I add a call to the JBoss server in the entrypoint script, it runs, but while I can access localhost:8080, I can't access localhost:8080/myapp.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong. I was trying to use

```
/opt/eap/bin/standalone.sh
```

as the last command in my entrypoint script.

I discovered this was wrong by calling

```
docker images inspect myapp:latest
```

where I found

```
"Cmd": [
                "/opt/eap/bin/openshift-launch.sh"
            ],
```

I was calling the wrong command. So I fixed this by replacing the command in my shell script and changing my ENTRYPOINT to CMD.

Here are the corrected files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/jboss-eap-7/eap71-openshift
USER root
RUN rpm -i [too many libraries] 
ADD subversion_installer_1.14.1.sh /home/svn_installer.sh
ADD svnvars.cfg /var/svn/svnvars.cfg
RUN yes | /home/svn_installer.sh 
USER jboss
ARG REPO_USER
ARG REPO_PW
ARG REPO_URL
ENV REPO_USER=$REPO_USER
ENV REPO_PW=$REPO_PW
ENV REPO_URL=$REPO_URL
ADD entrypoint.sh /home/entrypoint.sh
CMD /home/entrypoint.sh
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

svn export --username="$REPO_USER" --password="$REPO_PW" "$REPO_URL" /usr/svn/myapp
cd /usr/svn/myapp
ant war
/opt/eap/bin/openshift-launch.sh
```